# Recurrency in Azure and WebApi

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, service

I have implemented a WebApi that is now running in Azure. Now I need to implement a recurrent service that will run everyday. The main problem is I do now know the best and safer way to achieve it since I have never done anything like it.

I know that in Azure I can create a configurable scheduler or webjob that will call an endpoint recurrently, but for that I think my WebApi needs to expose the endpoint to be accessed. To be honest, this would facilitate my life since I have all my code there with easy access to the storages and stuff, but I have no idea if it can't cause a security problem.

I also read about Fluent Scheduler which can run in my WebApi and I liked this approach, but sincerely I do not know what is the best way to achieve what I pretend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a WebJob and use the Azure Scheduler to schedule it to run once per day at a set time.

Microsoft has some [great documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs), check out the section "Create a scheduled WebJob using the Azure Scheduler".

Comment: I already read this... My doubt is, following this approach don't I need to expose a webmethod in my api to be accessed by the webjob?

Comment: When you create the WebJob an endpoint is created for you, you don't need to create one specifically.

Comment: i will accept your answer... do you know any tutorial to how to create jobs in my webapi? because to be honest I have no idea how to do it... i created a Azure Webjob project but, I'm stuck, never used it and I have no idea how